# Как в админке битрикса - в составе заказа - вывести вес продукта?

Tags: php, битрикс, интернет-магазин

Всем привет.
Мне нужно в админке - в заказе - в составе заказа вывести вес продукта (напротив каждого продукта, там как мини корзина).
И я совсем не знаю как.. Подскажите, куда копать.. Это не свойства заказа, а состав.

https://prnt.sc/xcl1dq

Вывести нужно вот этот вес (это свойство элемента в торговом каталоге):

https://prnt.sc/xcl80v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение:
Для элементов каталоге создано новое свойство Вес, в него массово (в списке элементов все галочки и кнопка редактировать, заранее вывести 2 столбика Весов) продублированы все весы.
Далее в конкретном заказе нажать "Изменить заказ" и ниже, в составе заказа, при клике на бургер - кнопка редактирования колонок - там можно выводить пользовательские свойства элементов в составе заказа.